# WiFi stopped working (dhcpd times out) after enabling device encryption

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean, encryption, aokp

On my Samsung Galaxy Nexus running AOKP 4.2 JellyBean, WiFi has worked without issue before on this exact same hotspot, and it is currently working for other devices, so I'm assuming the error is in the phone. After trying another hotspot, I could see that the WiFi is definitely dead. But after enabling encryption on my device, it gets stuck in a loop. It detects the actual network, but it goes like this:

Saved with X authentication > Authenticating>  Obtaining IP address >  (Repeat)

I also tried deleting the network and adding it again without success, thinking it had something to do with the cached WPA key.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot before I just wipe and reinstall? Is this some kind of known issue?

Comment: Try to connect your device with ADB and have a look at the `adb logcat` for error messages. You don't need to install the entire SDK for this: The [ADB Guide](http://androidforums.com/faqs/443072-adb-guide-updated-12-05-2011-a.html) on AndroidForums contains a "MiniSDK" (Linux, Mac, Windows versions) to download which should be fully sufficient for this. Report back then with conrete error messages.

Comment: I found something interesting, not sure what else to look for as I don't feel like posting all of the 9k+ lines I got would make sense, also there's some personal info in there. Anyway, I found this: `E/DhcpStateMachine( 1029): DHCP failed on wlan0: Timed out waiting for dhcpcd to start`

Comment: Here's some more from the logs, tried to clean it up as well as I could: http://pastebin.com/LL9vFhL0

Comment: That looks like your router does not want to talk to your device. Might be a MAC filter. Try looking up your device's MAC address, and check whether this is permitted to connect to your WiFi (who knows, maybe encryption also encrypted your MAC address ;)

Comment: @Izzy it most definitely is not, exactly the same on two separate hotspots that have previously worked. I think the DHCP negotiation is timing out extremely fast for some reason. Oh well, time to wipe I guess.

Comment: Also worth a try. But if your router provides a log, I'd check that first (maybe something wrong with the lease, or whatever).

Comment: Are you seriously assuming that two different routers at two different locations that have both worked before have produced the same error on the same day, rather than something has happened with my phone?

Comment: Not likely, true (I obviously didn't sort the "two hotspots" from your comment into the correct context, sorry for that) -- but the logs could provide you with other useful information. It was just a suggestion, a shot in the dark. Do as you please ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might be some interoperability issue with a particular hotspot. If it is a DHCP time-out, you can try assigning a manual IP address to the particular network.

Or if it is a rooted device, you can try the below command inside `adb shell`:

```
dhcpcd wlan0
```

Comment: It's not related to the particular hotspot, read my post again.

Comment: +1 for the terminal command. Helped me to find out the file permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [the 4th revision of the OP's question](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/38734/4),

> Re-locked and unlocked bootloader, flashed recovery via Galaxy Nexus Toolkit and pushed a new AOKP via ADB, installed it and everything is working fine now. No idea what caused it, but I'm pretty sure the full device encryption screwed something up. However, since CWM doesn't even support full device encryption, it feels like a bug relating to it is kind of low priority since people shouldn't encrypt their devices with customs ROMs anyway and expect a smooth ride.